# Using shared memory in iOS

Tags: ios, boost, shared-memory

Is there any way to use shared memory in iOS?

I'm using Boost library (in C++ lib project) and when I want to initialize shared memory object:

```
shared_memory_object(open_or_create, "sharedMemoryVideo", read_write);
```

I'm getting an error, but only on physical device (on simulator is working):

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception: Operation not permitted
```

I'm using the last version of boost library (v1.70).

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

I used classical way with C pointers to store the data.